Can't access a nested set for dynamic blocks
I have a set with a set inside it. I want to access the nested sets for dynamic blocks but I can't figure out how to do this.
variable "test" {
  type = set(object({
    sdfsdfs           = string
    sxdfsdfsd         = string

    nestedone         = set(object({
      label           = string
      conditions      = set(object({ expression = string }))
      actions         = object({ route_to = string })
    }))

    nestedtwo         = set(object({
      label           = string
      conditions      = set(object({ expression = string }))
      actions         = object({ route_to = string })
    }))
  }))
}

I'm not looping over the entire pagerduty_event_orchestration_router resource just the rules blocks.
resource "pagerduty_event_orchestration_router" "test" {
dynamic "rule" {

  # this isn't working
  for_each = var.test[*].nestedone

  content {
    label = rule.value.label
    dynamic "condition" {
      for_each = rule.value.conditions
      content {
        expression = condition.value.expression
      }
    }
    dynamic "actions" {
      for_each = rule.value.actions
      content {
        route_to = actions.value
      }
    }
  }
}

How do I loop over var.test.nestedone and var.test.nestedtwo inside a resource? Again I'm not looping over and create multiple instances of the resource.

your actions is an object you can not loop on that

have you tried flatten(var.test[*].nestedone) or toset(flatten(var.test[*].nestedone))

This works, but I really don't like the indexing into a single item list.
resource "pagerduty_event_orchestration_router" "test" {
    ....
    dynamic "rule" {
    
      for_each = [for i in var.test : {for r in i.nestedone : r.label => r}][0]
    
      content {
        label = rule.value.label
        dynamic "condition" {
          for_each = rule.value.conditions
          content {
            expression = condition.value.expression
          }
        }
        dynamic "actions" {
          for_each = rule.value.actions
          content {
            route_to = actions.value
          }
        }
      }
}

Would like to know if this is the only way to do this. I had to generate a list and index into it. I'm also worried if using a list will bite me even though it should only ever have a single element here.

does it really work? that [0] will select just the first one
